# FuncAnimation not iterable

Tags: animation, matplotlib

I'd like to create 2 animations and save them to one file, but get the error:
TypeError: 'FuncAnimation' object is not iterable

Separately each animation runs fine.

Here's a minimal-ish example that demonstrates the problem. The cosmetic stuff like ax.text and ax.axhline may help show what I'm trying to do, but is not essential to the problem. I'm running the code in a Jupyter notebook.

Thanks for any help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

xdata = np.array([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8])
ydata = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,1.25))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 0.5)
ax.barh(0, 1, align='center', height=0.7, color='.95', ec='None', zorder=-20)
ax.axhline(0, 0, 1, color='0.25', linewidth=.5)
ax.text(0, -0.45, "0", verticalalignment = "center", horizontalalignment="center", fontsize=10)
ax.text(1, -0.45, "1", verticalalignment = "center", horizontalalignment="center", fontsize=10)
ax.text(-0.01, 0, "0", verticalalignment = "center", horizontalalignment="center", fontsize=10)
ax.text(0.75, -0.45, "3/4", verticalalignment = "center", horizontalalignment="center", fontsize=10)
ax.axvline(0.75, 0.15, 0.85, color='.5', linestyle='dotted', linewidth=0.75)

line, = ax.plot(xdata, ydata, 'ro', markersize=7)

def init0():     # initialization function for first animation
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return line,

def init1():     # second animation
    ax.set_xlim(0.5, 1)
    ax.text(0.5, -0.45, "1/2", verticalalignment = "center", horizontalalignment="center", fontsize=10)
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return line,

def animate(i):     # update function
    ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    return line,

# call animators
anim0 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init0, frames=150, interval=20, blit=True)
anim1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init1, frames=150, interval=20, blit=True)


fig.set_size_inches(16, 2.5, True)     # improve resolution in animation
plt.axis('off')

anim0.save('anims.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'], extra_anim=anim1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Second request. I could really use some help with this question. I spent this morning trying to get ArtistAnimation to work, but basically got the same error. Running the code in the python shell also gives the same error, but this eliminates Jupyter as the problem. ... Internet searches turn up close matches, but nothing that I've tried has worked. I've also read Benjamin Root's chapter on Animations in his 2015 book about interactive visualizations with matplotlib. Again, no solution. I must be missing something very fundamental, and I sure would like to understand what it is. Thanks!

Comment: If it would be helpful for me to make the code truly minimal, I'd be happy to do that. I can also easily supply the full error message if that would help. I suspect the source of the error may occur because Line2D objects are not iterable, but this hasn't yet helped with a solution.